# Listbox item stay focused after selection

Tags: c#, wpf

I don't know if the title express what I want. I have a ListBox in WPF where I generate many elements. When I click on a element while still generating I want my selected item to not move down the list, so I cannot see it anymore, I want to stay in the exact position where I click on it.

If this is possible, can someone point some ideas on how to do it in C#?

Thanks.

Comment: What UI, Winforms, WPF, ASP .NET?

Comment: ah, sorry, I forgot to say: WPF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is even a good idea and that you are using winforms

Step 1:

Determine the index of the selected item in the source.

Step 2:

When your adding items to the `ListBox` split the `ListBox` at the index where the item previously was insert the item at that point, then add on the remainder of the items, while making sure that you've removed the item if it is now elsewhere in the list.

Code:

//Let's assume that you know how to get the position of the item when it is clicked and save the 
//item to a variable called OriginalItem

```
public void PutTheItemInTheSameSpot()
{
   var listboxitems = (List<Integer>)YourListBox.DataSource;

   var originalClikedItem = OriginalItem;
   var topPart = new List<Integer>();

   for (i = 0; i < itemPosition; i++)
   {
       topPart.Add(listboxItems[i]);
   }
   topPart.Add(originalClickedItem);

   var bottomPart = listboxitems.Remove(toppart);

   YourListBox.DataSource = toppart.AddRange(bottomPart);


}
```

---

Saw your edit about it being WPF

The could should work in idea.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the ideea, why I want this, its because, I can right click on the item and to something with it, but when I select the item it then disapears, so it's kind of annoying

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought: you could try having your view respond to an event whenever an item is added to your ListBox. In the event handler, you could force the selected item to scroll into view presumably keeping it in the current "viewable" position:

```
listBox.ScrollIntoView(listBox.SelectedItem);
```

I've never tried this before so it may or may not produce the desired affect?